# How is the ternary expansion of $1=0.222...$?

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion

I understand how the ternary expansion of $1=1.00$... but I don't understand how $1=0.22$... .

Comment: Do you understand why in base 10 that 1=0.9999999.....?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that in base $3$, $1\neq 0.022\ldots$, but $1 = 0.22\ldots$.

Comment: In both cases $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n 2*3 {i+1}=\lim \frac 13 - \frac 1 {3^n} $.  Just like $\lim\sum 9*10^i=1-10^{-n} $.

Comment: Right.  0.1 = 1/3 and 0.022222 = 1/3.  1=0.2222222.......

Answer (score 4):

In ternary:

$\begin{eqnarray}0.222222... & = & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}2\frac 1 {3^i}\\
& = & \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}2\frac 1 {3^i}\\
& = & \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}1 -\frac 1 {3^{n}}\\
& = & 1.\end{eqnarray}$

This is the exact same reason why $0.99999...=1$ in base $10.$